# Jquery datepicker restrict dates in second date field based on selected date in first date field and wise versa

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Jquery datepicker restrict dates in second date field based on selected date in first date field and wise versa(restrict dates in first date field based on selected date in second date field)

i have 2 text boxes FromDate and Todate
it depends on user which field he will be choosing first, he has 2 option fromdate and todate.

if user, 1st selects fromdate ex(15 June 2017) then in the Todate field all the previous dates selected in fromdate will be blocked, and Todate field will only be available to choose future dates

if user, 1st selects Todate ex(15 June 2017) then in the Fromdate field all the future dates  will be blocked and Fromdate field will only be available to choose past dates

another example
if fromdate is selected as (15 June 2017) then todate will not be able to select dates less then 15 June 2017 ,todate will only be available to select dates grteate then 15 June 2017.

if Todate is selected as (15 June 2017) then fromdate will not be able to select dates greater then 15 June 2017,fromdate will only be available to select dates less then 15 June 2017.

below is my code

```
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, "{0:d}", new { tabindex = "2", @class = "form-control" })
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>

                                    </div>
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, "{0:d}", new { tabindex = "3", @class = "form-control" })
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>

                                    </div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var date_input = $('#datetimepicker1'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    var options = {
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
    };
    date_input.datepicker(options);
})

$(document).ready(function () {
    var date_input = $('#datetimepicker2'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    var options = {
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
    };
    date_input.datepicker(options);
})
</script>
```

Comment: yes this is possible, what did you try ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/PPSh3/3/ this fiddle is some what similar but not exactly my answer

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for you:

```
$("#FromDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
         yearRange: '-30:+1',
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            //self.validateDate();            
        },
        onClose: function (selectedDate, instance) {
            if (selectedDate !== '') {               
                var orginalDate = new Date(selectedDate);
                var date = new Date(new Date(orginalDate).setMonth(orginalDate.getMonth() + 3));
                $("#ToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                $("#ToDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);


            }
        }
    });
    $("#ToDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-30:+1',       

        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            //self.validateDate();
        },
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            var orginalDate = new Date(selectedDate);
            var date = new Date(new Date(orginalDate).setMonth(orginalDate.getMonth() -3 ));
            $("#FromDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
            $("#FromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }        
    });
```

Comment: I have tried with the above code it didnot worked(or may be i would have missed something)..can you please see the question i have edited ...

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution
Problem was in my datepicker jquery
below is the code i use and it worked very well

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#from').datepicker(
     {

         beforeShow: function () {
             $(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#to').val());
         }
     });
$('#to').datepicker(
         {
             defaultDate: "+1w",
             beforeShow: function () {
                 $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#from').val());
                 if ($('#from').val() === '') $(this).datepicker('option');
             }
         });
})
```

```
<div> 

    <label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from" class="form-control datepicker" /> <label for="to">to</label> <input type="text" id="to" class="form-control datepicker" name="to" />
</div>
```